# Receive video intent from gallery or browsable file manager in Android

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I tried almost everything to receive a video intent from another application, but it is just somehow not possible for me.
Here are my activities intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    <data android:scheme="*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:scheme="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who does as well not receive an intent, [here](https://github.com/nova-video-player/aos-Video/blob/androidx/AndroidManifest.xml) is a manifest with working intent filters.